# Use username to generate Key in the cache

Tags: c#, .net, caching, memcached, unity-container

I have crosscutting project that can be access anywhere in the aplicattion 
Something like this.

```
//Domain\username     
public static string GetLoggedUserName()
        {
            return Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
        }
```

And when I need to clean the cache (update, delete, etc) I do this.

```
private IMethodReturn ApplyCleanCacheHandler(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        var methodClass = input.MethodBase.DeclaringType.Name;
        var sessionUserName = SomeSessionClass.GetLoggedUserName();

        var cacheKeysToClean = GlobalCachingProvider.GetAllCacheKeys()
                                                    .Where(x => x.Contains(methodClass) &&
                                                               (x.Contains(GlobalCachingProvider.commonCacheUser) || 
                                                                x.Contains(sessionUserName))).ToList();

        cacheKeysToClean.ForEach(key => GlobalCachingProvider.RemoveItem(key));

        // Original target invoking.
        return getNext()(input, getNext);
    }
```

Its there anyway to do this better, I don't know if its a good practice access to the username anywhere of the aplication.

Comment: What are you really asking for?  This code works and you haven't mentioned any criteria for a more optimal solution.

Comment: I feel that I could be done better, for instance, keep using the username, but not putting globally.